# HTML page size adapts correctly on window resize but does not on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am trying to implement a responsive web page. I mostly used percentage "%" for sizing. It is working fine if you resize page on high resolution to lower manually.

But if you load page on low resolution it somehow fails to adapt (works fine if you resize manually again).

Here is the link http://slavesofdestiny.com/kaanproje/

I did not separated css and scripts from index yet so all of the code is in one page.(it is normally my band's domain) any suggestions?

Edit: I also forgot to mention that I am using fullPage.js plugin.

Thanks!

Code:

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-left">
                <li data-menuanchor="section1"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#HiddenTrack">HIDDEN TRACK</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="section2"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Hizmetlerimiz">HİZMETLERİMİZ</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="section3"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Musterilerimiz">MÜŞTERİLERİMİZ</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="section4"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Portfolyo">PORTFOLYO</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="section5"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Iletisim">İLETİŞİM</a></li>
            </ul>
        <ul id="menu-right">
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/hiddentracktr" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="https://twitter.com/HiddenTrackTR" target="_blank">TWITTER</a></li>
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hidden-track-creative" target="_blank">LINKEDIN</a></li>
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UChJGAyoLFqr2qgLSY4b4BSw" target="_blank">YOUTUBE</a></li>
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="http://hiddentrackcreative.tumblr.com" target="_blank">TUMBLR</a></li>
            <li><a class="right-menu-link" href="https://www.behance.net/hiddentrackcreative" target="_blank">BEHANCE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="http://www.hiddentrack.com"><img id="hiddentrack-vector" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 45%; width: 10em;" src="Vector-Smart-Object.png" alt="Hidden Track"></a>
        <img style="float: right; margin-top: 2%; width: 250px;" id="mobile-ht-logo" src="hiddentrackfooter.png" alt="Hidden Track Logo">
        <div id="mobile-menu"  class="dl-menuwrapper">
            <button id="menu-button" class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
            <ul class="dl-menu" id="mobile-menu-ul">
                    <li data-menuanchor="section1"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#HiddenTrack">HIDDEN TRACK</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="section2"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Hizmetlerimiz">HİZMETLERİMİZ</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="section3"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Musterilerimiz">MÜŞTERİLERİMİZ</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="section4"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Portfolyo">PORTFOLYO</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="section5"><a class="left-menu-link" href="#Iletisim">İLETİŞİM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<div id="fullpage">
<div id="section1" class="section">
    <div id="HT-hello">
        <div id="HT-Hello-Main-Image">
            <h1 style="font-family: Oswald-Bold; font-size: 1066%; color: #72c4d6; margin-top: 6.5%;">SOCIAL & DESIGN</h1>
            <hr style="width: 150px; color: #72c4d6; margin-top: -100px;">
            <h3 style="font-family: PT_Sans-Italic; font-size: 186%; color: #72c4d6">
                ''Para kazanmak sanattır, çalışmak sanattır ama iyi iş yapmak en iyi sanattır.'' <br>(Andy Warhol)
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="down-button"><a href="#Hizmetlerimiz"><img src="downIcon.png" alt="Down Icon"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="section">
    <div id="HT-ht">
        <img style="width: 60%;" src="vso.png" alt="Hidden Track">
        <hr style="width: 150px; color: #72c4d6; margin-top: 50px;">
        <h3 style="font-family: PT_Sans-Italic; font-size: 220%; color: #72c4d6">2012 yılında kurulmuş multidispliner, kreatif bir oluşumdur. <br>Hizmet verdiği markaların iletişim problemlerini çözmeyi amaçlar. Markanızın <br>gereksinim duyduğu konularda stratejik çözümler sunar.</h3>
        <img style="width: 40%;" src="SOCIAL-&-DESIGN.png" alt="Social and Design">
    </div>
    <div class="down-button"><a href="#Musterilerimiz"><img src="downIcon.png" alt="Down Icon"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="section">
    <div style="" class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
        <div style="text-align: left; width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <h1 style=" float: left; color: #72c4d6; font-family: PT_Sans-Bold; font-size: 650%;">MARKALAŞMA,</h1>
        <img style="float: right; width: 20%; margin-top: 3%;" src="fingerprint.png" alt="Finger Print">
        <h3 style="float: left; color: #72c4d6; font-family: PT_Sans-Italic; font-size: 155%; margin-top: -7.5%;">süreciniz için altyapı oluşturuyor, kararlılıkla devam politikası öneriyoruz. </h3>
        <h3 style="float: left; color: #72c4d6; font-family: PT_Sans; font-size: 135%; margin-top: -4%;">Unutmayın ki, bir marka müşterileri nezdinde kararlı algılanan değere<br> sahip olduğu sürece pazar performansı da buna paralel olarak artacaktır.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"> Slide 4 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide5"> Slide 5 </div>
</div>
<div id="section4" class="section">
    <h1>Section 4</h1>
</div>
<div id="section5" class="section">
    <h1>Section 5</h1>
</div>
</div>
<script src="ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/js/jquery.dlmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
$('#mobile-menu').dlmenu({
        animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', 'ffffff'],
        anchors: ['HiddenTrack', 'Hizmetlerimiz', 'Musterilerimiz', 'Portfolyo', 'Iletisim'],
        menu: 'menu-left',
        css: true,
        loopBottom: true
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){ $.fn.fullpage.reBuild(); });
$(document).ready(function (){
if(jQuery.browser.mobile){
    $('#mobile-menu').show();
    $('#mobile-ht-logo').show();
    $('#menu-button').show();
    $('#mobile-menu-ul').show();
    $('#menu-right').hide();
    $('#menu-left').hide();
    $('#hiddentrack-vector').hide();



    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    /*if(windowWidth <= windowHeight){
        $('#HT-Hello-Main-Image').css("background-image","none");
    }else{
        $('#HT-Hello-Main-Image').css("background-image","url('hello.png')");
        $('#HT-Hello-Main-Image').css("width", "100%");
    }*/
}
});

    $(document).ready(function (){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(!jQuery.browser.mobile){
        $('#mobile-ht-logo').hide();
        $('#menu-button').hide();
        $('#mobile-menu').hide();
        if(windowWidth <= $(window).height()){
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            autoScrolling:false
        });
        }
}
});
```

CSS:

```
   li{
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #menu{
        position:fixed;
        margin-top: auto;
        height: 9%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #72c4d6;
        z-index:9;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        display: inline;
    }
    #menu-container{
        //margin-left: 100px;
        //margin-right: 100px;
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #menu-left{
        float: left;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 44%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #menu-right{
        float: right;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 44%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .section{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .left-menu-link{
        font-family: PT_Sans;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 105%;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 2.2%;
    }
    .right-menu-link{
        font-family: PT_Sans;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 105%;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 4%;
    }
    // Menu Finish
    #HT-hello{
        top: 0px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #HT-ht{

    }
    #HT-Hello-Main-Image{
        background: url("hello.png") center;
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        top: 50px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 70px;
    }
    .down-button{
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 50px; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        margin: auto; 
        width: 50px;
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "PT_Sans";
        src: url('libs/PT_Sans/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "PT_Sans-Bold";
        src: url('libs/PT_Sans/PT_Sans-Web-Bold.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "PT_Sans-Italic";
        src: url('libs/PT_Sans/PT_Sans-Web-Italic.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "PT_Sans-BoldItalic";
        src: url('libs/PT_Sans/PT_Sans-Web-BoldItalic.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "Oswald-Regular";
        src: url('libs/Oswald/Oswald-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "Oswald-Bold";
        src: url('libs/Oswald/Oswald-Bold.ttf');
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: "Oswald-Light";
        src: url('libs/Oswald/Oswald-Light.ttf');
    }
```

Comment: Please include sample code in your questions. Links can break and sites can change. This also allows users years from now searching from the same answer to be able to see your code, and it also helps us determine where your trouble areas are.

Comment: You are right I will edit it as soon as I got a good internet connection! Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your problem is with the Jquery FullPage plugin.

The problem is that the script is not making changes onload and doesn't work well with your design.
You should add this line on your `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $.fn.fullpage.reBuild() });
```

Also if you want to do a responsive page that adapt depending on size you should really look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)